# How to handle dependent streams and providers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, provider, state-management

So I have one independent auth stream:

```dart
StreamProvider.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(), initialData: null),
```

I have a stream that depends on this stream so whenever the auth user changes it should rebuild or refetch data but should also act as a stream itself.

```dart
Stream<List<Patient>> streamPatients() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(auth_user_id)
      .collection('patients')
      .snapshots()
      .map((list) =>
          list.docs.map((snap) => Patient.fromFirestore(snap)).toList());
}
```

Here the `auth_user_id` should be the auth user's id from the first stream.

Then I have a provider so that users can select which `Patient` should be active.

As an example when the user is not logged in the streamPatient and the Patient should be null. However, when the auth state changes AKA the user logs in it should refetch the data from Firestore populating the stream and that should trigger the PatientProvider to "select" the first patient in the list.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: "[...] but should also act as a stream itself [...] What is the easiest way to do this?" https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncExpand.html

Comment: you can also create sn `async*` generator if you want, more here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch

Comment: @pskink can you give a code example of that in this case?

Comment: example of `asyncExpand`?

Comment: An example of how to make one stream dependent on another and a provider dependent on the stream that depends on a stream with `asyncExpand`

Comment: authStream.asyncExpand((authData) => someStreamThatDependsOnAuthData(authData))